# Comunication between two hosts with grpc in python

Tags: python, grpc

I have written a simple script in python using grpc making communicate  two processes in localhost.
Now i want to make comunicate two processes running in two different computers.

I have tried to change the port and the ip address of the server but is not working.

This is my client :

```
 def run():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
      print("Usage : python controller_agent.py <server-ip-address>")
      exit(0)
    with grpc.insecure_channel('%s:50051' % sys.argv[1]) as channel:
      stub = controller_agent_pb2_grpc.AgentServiceStub(channel)
      message_in = input('Message : ')
      response = stub.EchoMessage(controller_agent_pb2.EchoRequest(message=message_in))
    print(response.message)
```

And this is my server :

```
_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24


class RouterAgent(controller_agent_pb2_grpc.AgentServiceServicer):

    def EchoMessage(self, request, context):
        print("Echo : %s" %request.message)
        return controller_agent_pb2.EchoReply(message="Echo : %s" % request.message)


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    controller_agent_pb2_grpc.add_AgentServiceServicer_to_server(RouterAgent(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)
```

How can i change the code to make working the script not only on localhost ?

This is the error message when i try to comunicate to a remote host

[image]

Comment: Do you have an error message or trace log available? Does the machine your server is running on have the port gRPC is bound to open?

Comment: i've added the error message.

Comment: Seems to be a firewall issue. I would make sure port 50051 is open for inbound TCP connections on the server side.

Comment: Can you verify that the hostname you're connecting to is resolvable? Perhaps using a tools like nslookup or dig.